# How to put json data fetched from an api into a react state array?

Tags: java, reactjs, fetch

I am using this API for weather called [OpenWeatherMap](https://openweathermap.org/). Essentially I first retrieve the latitude and longitude of the user location, since the API requires the users coordinates. Then I created a state for the weather JSON making it an array.

[image]

Then I use JS's fetch to fetch data from the server to retrieve the JSON in the form of a promise. And I then created a const to store this retrieved information after which I use the useState method to update my state. Finally, I check if the coordinates are null and if they aren't I call the async function to retrieve information.

[image]

However, when I run my React app this happens in the console log:
[image]

The numbers next to weather[Object] keep increasing and I am expecting to get a JSON.

Am I updating the state wrong or something? What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  you are updating state wrong. Your `...whether` is adding your previous data plus new data you get so if you are only looking for new data then remove `...whether`, and if if it is something else, please clarify.

All you need to do is create `const weather = <your data>` and then push that to state by assigning how you are doing in screenshot. In nutshell, I see `...whether` as not required there. `setState({longiturde: longitude, lattitude: lattitudeData`})